# Exercise on bounded operator on L2 space

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

> Let $H = L^2([0,3])$ and let $T \in B(H)$ defined by: $$Tu(t) =
>  (1+t^2)u(t)$$ $||T||_{op} = 10$.
>
> i) Is T compact? **Justify** the answer.
>
> ii) Does $T$ have eigenvalues? **Justify** the answer.

---

If you may help me even on just one point this would be very helpfull really.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$i).\ $ Scale to $[0,1]$ and note that $\{e^{int}\}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis. Now show that the sequence defined by $f_n(t)=(1+t^2)e^{int}$ has no Cauchy subesequence.

$ii).\ $ Note that $Tf(t)-\lambda f(t)=0\Leftrightarrow (1+t^2)f(t)=\lambda f(t)$

Comment: Thank you fo the answer! :)

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help.